# Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java

I am getting this

```
Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException         at
java.util.AbstractList$Itr.checkForComodification(AbstractList.java:372) at 
java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:343)         at
org.apache.struts2.components.IteratorComponent.end(IteratorComponent.java:334) at
org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.IteratorTag.doAfterBody(IteratorTag.java:87)
```

error frequently.. due to this my application server getting out of memory issue. Can you please help me out.

My JSP code is:

```
<tr>                

  <td><input type="radio" name ="aa" onclick="selectAll('<s:property value="trainNoDn" />','<s:property value="stnDn" />','<s:property value="stDn" />','<s:property value="locoDn" />','<s:property value="trainDateHidd" />')" ></td> 

  <td><s:textfield id="trainNoDn" name="trainNoDn" value="%{trainNoDn}" size="10" cssStyle=" font-size: 100%;background-color:white"  tabindex="-1" onfocus="blur();"/></td>

  <td><s:textfield id="stnDn" name="stnDn" value="%{stnDn}" size="6" cssStyle=" font-size: 100%;background-color:white"   tabindex="-1" onfocus="blur();"/> </td>

  <td><s:textfield id="stDn" name="stDn" value="%{stDn}" size="2" cssStyle=" font-size: 100%;background-color:white"   tabindex="-1" onfocus="blur();"/> </td>

  <td><s:textfield id="actDtDn" name="actDtDn" value="%{actDtDn}" size="5" cssStyle=" font-size: 100%;background-color:white"   tabindex="-1" onfocus="blur();" /> </td>

  <td><s:textfield id="locoDn" name="locoDn" value="%{locoDn}"  size="4" cssStyle=" font-size: 100%;background-color:white" tabindex="-1" onfocus="blur();" /></td>

  <td> <s:hidden name="ottkBean.trainDateHidd" id="trainDateHidd" value="%{trainDateHidd}" ></s:hidden> </td>

</tr>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: There is something wrong with the iterator. The ConcurrentModificationException will be thrown, if you change a List within a loop or with an iterator while iterating over the elements.

Comment: Sir,Can u explain me how to change the List within the loop

Comment: Note the indexes of the items to be changed/deleted in another list while iterating and change/delete them after the loop. Be careful with indexes. Maybe its better to operate on the Item itself because of changing indexes.